How to name each screen?
I have a list of screens like this.
root@123:~# screen -ls
There are screens on:
    12497.1 (09/13/2024 10:58:02 PM)    (Attached)
    12416.2 (09/13/2024 10:51:26 PM)    (Attached)
    11988.3 (09/13/2024 10:45:50 PM)    (Attached)
    11974.4 (09/13/2024 10:45:49 PM)    (Attached)
    11981.5 (09/13/2024 10:45:49 PM)    (Attached)
    11946.6 (09/13/2024 10:45:48 PM)    (Attached)
    11953.7 (09/13/2024 10:45:48 PM)    (Attached)
    11960.8 (09/13/2024 10:45:48 PM)    (Attached)
    11890.9 (09/13/2024 10:45:47 PM)    (Attached)
    11897.10    (09/13/2024 10:45:47 PM)    (Attached)
    11904.11    (09/13/2024 10:45:47 PM)    (Attached)
    11876.12    (09/13/2024 10:45:46 PM)    (Attached)
12 Sockets in /run/screen/S-root.

And also this code to display all screens on one screen.
#!/bin/bash

# Check if the script is run inside tmux
if [ -n "$TMUX" ]; then
    echo "Script should not be run inside tmux. Please exit tmux and try again."
    exit 1
fi

# Kill existing tmux session if exists
tmux kill-session -t mysession1 2>/dev/null

# Create a new tmux session
tmux new-session -d -s mysession1

# Get all screen session IDs, filtering out non-numeric identifiers
SESSION_IDS=$(screen -ls | awk '/\t/ {print $1}' | grep -E '^[0-9]+' | cut -d'.' -f1 | sort -u)
echo "All screen session IDs: $SESSION_IDS"

if [ -z "$SESSION_IDS" ]; then
    echo "No active screen sessions found."
    exit 1
fi

# Function to add new panes in tmux
add_pane() {
    local session_id=$1
    tmux split-window -t mysession1
    tmux send-keys -t mysession1 "screen -x $session_id" C-m
    tmux select-layout -t mysession1 tiled
}

# Create first pane
first_session_id=$(echo "$SESSION_IDS" | head -n1)
tmux send-keys -t mysession1 "screen -x $first_session_id" C-m

# Add remaining panes
echo "$SESSION_IDS" | tail -n +2 | while read -r session_id; do
    echo "Adding pane for session: $session_id"
    add_pane $session_id
done

# Set window layout to tiled
tmux select-layout -t mysession1 tiled

# Attach to the tmux session
tmux attach -t mysession1

But the problem is that with 10+ screens I don't understand which one is which. How can I sign each terminal or at least sign the active screen I am on at the bottom?
I tried asking chatgpt, but he didn't give the right code.

For example, so that it is signed at the top left or top exactly with the name of the screen, not the ID: https://i.imgur.com/c8Je8LD.png.

Use Ctrl+a A to set the title of the screen. Is that what you want?

@choroba I think so, but I need the script to name each screen based on the screen -ls and I would see (in this case the numbers 1 2 3 on the top right as in the screenshot).
